# Can you enable Adobe Dreamweaver CS5 to handle and edit extensionless files?

Tags: dreamweaver, adobe-cs5

For example: gemfile, config, and all other file names with no extensions.

Comment: Is this a windows question, i.e. "Can windows assosiate extensionless files with a program?" or a Dreamweaver question "It won't open files of unknown extension"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## [Dreamweaver CC - How to open extensionless files](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNhbT.png)

Adobe Dreamweaver CC (13.0):

- `Edit` > `Preferences` > Category: `File Types / Editors`
- Add a new extension and just type a dot: `.`
- Associate Dreamweaver to it in the `Editors` column (or Notepad, or Sublime Text)

Extensionless files like *gemfile*, *config*, *error_log* will open up now.

Comment: confirm this works especially for error_log  - finally a simple answer to a long standing and annoying bug!

Answer (score 1):

If its the first look [here](http://perishablepress.com/press/2006/08/08/associate-extensionless-files-with-notepad/). For windows 7 see [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/236014)